# Could you electrically charge a liquid or granules to refuel EVs with it?

Tags: electricity, everyday-life, batteries, thermoelectricity

Is there a physical law that would make an electrically charged liquid or granules impossible to produce? Theoretically it should be possible to refuel an EV by adding two different liquids to it in two enclosed storage tanks, one positively charged and one negatively. Once the energy is used you just empty the tanks and add new charged fluids. Please help me to grasp why that would be infeasible.

Comment: Why do you wanna make it liquid or granulous? **If** you could build up a significant charge on any microscopic stuff and connect them you'd have your current, I dont get why you want specifically a liquid. And to answer your question. An object that has been charged is unstable. How do you plan to store your charged object without having it discharging immediately to its surroundings (which might be you)? Charged stuff don't keep their charge unless you do something towards that goal. And well then that's how every circuit work, finding a way to maintain a potential difference

Comment: I think he was thinking that a charged liquid could be easily filled into the tank, e.g., in a petrol station, and would be easier than replacing solid batteries.

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe I don't really imagine the practical point of view with precision, but carrying a liquid container and filling my remote while being careful not to spill the charged liquid everywhere seems less convenient than changing a battery

Comment: Do you mean such as replacing the acid solution in a discharged lead acid battery?

Comment: This has been studied as a path to ultrafast 'recharging', which might involve replacing battery/capacitor fluids -- obviously you need a battery design where the electrodes are never degraded or absorbed.  The short answer is that it's completely unworkable for any existing battery design.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks for the input, my idea was that there should be a fast way to get the energy from the external source into the vehicle. Given that car batteries consist of many small cells that are connected instead of one big one, maybe you could just add new already charged cells: https://images.fastcompany.com/upload/panasonic-lithium-ion-battery-module.jpg

Imagine this blue cells, just 10x times smaller to be inserted while the old ones just get sucked out at the bottom at a "re-filling" station.

Comment: Note that rockets that use rocket fuel which is analogous to granules have their limitations. For example, you can't throttle or restart them. Coal power plants have grinders that grind the coal into dust and then blow it into the furnace with fans. Making that small and easily throttleable could be an issue.

Comment: >> the practical point of view with precision, but carrying a liquid container and filling my remote while being careful not to spill the charged liquid everywhere seems less convenient than changing a battery

---

@Barbaud Julien do you think it'll be even less practical than filling up a tank of  a fuel-cell vehicle with liquid hydrogen?

Answer (score 1):

It would be pretty tough to manage a liquid with a large net charge: its self repulsion would tend to make it fly apart explosively. Basically you are describing a large capacitor. Capacitors are usually energized by pushing electric current through wires, not charged liquid through pipes.

What you CAN do is store a bunch of positive and negative electric charge all mixed together in a liquid in a configuration such that you can extract energy. That is what liquid hydrogen is: a bunch of positive charges hanging out in pairs surrounded by an equal number of negative charges. The pairs of positive charges would much rather position themselves around oxygen atoms, and if you let them, energy is released.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, granules can carry battery-like charge; this is the principle of
the 'flow battery', and is a battery chemistry with two 'electrodes' which
are fluid enough to charge/pump into storage on energy intake, and
pump from storage/discharge to cover an energy need.

It is possible to do this with large-scale safe storage (it's not flammable)
and combine (which creates  reaction) only under complete control.
It isn't compact, however, since the usual application is the size
of a few big swimming pools for storage.   I'm told, in case of a spill,
the materials can be designed to be safe, even edible.